# How do I determine the probable path of a future flight?

Tags: commercial-aviation, passenger, navigation, flight-planning, flight-path

As a passenger on a regularly scheduled flight, how can I determine what areas my flight is likely to overfly?

I understand that inclement weather, other aircraft, and other outside influences (both somewhat predictable and completely unpredictable) can and will modify the planned route to some extent, which would be bonus information, but not necessary.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question, FlightAware is a good start. It shows the actual routes of previous flights, and even overlays the radar image from that time to show if weather affected the routing.

Comment: In commercial flights, time and fuel are major concerns.  Therefore, flights go as direct as possible.  A straight-line path from origin to destination will be pretty close to the actual route flown.